# How do I separate between integration testing and unit testing using Hapi in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nunit, hapi.js

How do I separate between integration testing and unit testing using Hapi in Node.js?

I am trying to reduce the testing time in our automations for every time we update a unit within our API.

I was wondering can I just create two new folders test/unit and test/int to separate the scripts and what would the update to the package.json require?

I have the following in the package.json which runs the .labrc.js
package.json

```
    "test": "npm run version-stamp && lab --bail -t 80 -r html -o coverage.html -r console -o stdout -r junit -o TestResult.xml -r lcov -o coverage.dat",
    "simple-test": "npm run version-stamp && lab",
    "test-int": "not sure what to put here",
```

labrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    timeout: 7500,
    lint: true,
    paths: [
        "test/init/aws",
        "test/unit/plugins",
        "test/unit/utils",
        "test/unit/routes"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure your approach sounds ok. Issue is that `lab` don't allow custom labrc to specify different paths for integration tests. but you can try to do something like this

Separate tests in two different directories

- `test/unit`
- `test/integration`

Provide an additional alternative `labrc.js` config file for integration tests and remove the one available in the root directory,

You will have two different `labrc.js` files

- `test/unit/labrc.js`
- `test/integration/labrc.js`

The one for Unit Test should look like

`test/unit/labrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    timeout: 7500,
    lint: true,
    paths: [
        "unit/plugins",
        "unit/utils",
        "unit/routes",
    ],
```

For **Integration Tests**

`test/unit/labrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    timeout: 7500,
    lint: true,
    paths: [
        "integration/aws",
    ],
```

In package.json

```json
{
    ... Lot of JSON config here
    "test": "npm run version-stamp && lab test/unit --bail -t 80 -r html -o coverage.html -r console -o stdout -r junit -o TestResult.xml -r lcov -o coverage.dat",
    "simple-test": "npm run version-stamp && lab test/unit",
    "test-integration": "lab test/integration", 
    ... Further JSON config here
}
```

*Customize the parameters passed to the lab*

As a Suggestion prefer *integration* over *int* It may be confusing.